# Migrate MUC (multi-user conference) data from Mnesia to MySQL in ejabberd

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

Ejabberd's `mod_muc` module supports `db_type` option, which can be either `internal` (Mnesia) or `odbc` (MySQL) to store MUC-related data.

Is it possible to migrate from Mnesia to MySQL saving all the information of established chat rooms?

Comment: @womble downvote just because of non-relevant tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a migration tool for the MUC content to migrate data from Mnesia to relational database.

If you still need that feature, I suggest you post a feature request on ejabberd issue tracker on Github: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues